# Subjugation casus beli

Tags: stellaris

My current situation: My empire is in federation. I've been successfully conquering chunks of Empire A (that is in defensive pact with Empire B) until my enemy has only 2-3 planets left and I've gathered enough unity to open (but not complete) the "Domination" tradition tree:

[image]
Yet I am unable to set the "Request subjugation" casus beli  - it is on the "Declare war" screen but it is greyed out saying "Your empire has no request subjugation claim".

How do I put such claim? All I can see is the "claim sector" option on the claims screen. Is the fact of me being in federation blocking it? Is the target empire still too big? If so, how can I know that the target is small enough (in 1.x you could see that when you were trying to set the war goals)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's changed with the recent updates and a lot of demands/casus belli now require you to be neighbors among some other requirements. The basis for demanding subjugation should be:

- Domination Tradition
- Superior in relative power
- Be their neighbor
- Ask/Demand in diplomacy screen prior, if they refuse you have a year to setup that war demand.

In that war it should be a pretty hefty warscore to win, likely 100.

Comment: You are right - there I need to first to propose the protectorate status and attack within 1 year

Comment: Just as a note: it is still impossible to subjugate too big empires - you will run into war weariness on both sides and the war will end with status quo